# Refactoring and optimization

Tags: optimization, coding-style, refactoring, computer-science

To me refactoring is mainly for the humans that will read and maintain the code after it is written. 
But in the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) article for refactoring it says:

> Advantages include improved code readability and reduced complexity to improve the maintainability of the source code, as well as a more expressive internal architecture or object model to improve extensibility.

Does the reduced complexity part only mean `make it less complex to understand` or does it also include `less complex calculations` for the computer to handle? And if so should I consider code optimization as a part of refactoring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no apriori reason to believe that refactored code is "more optimized" in terms of resources consumed during execution; refactoring is really about improving code maintainability. Often more maintainable code is less resource efficient than highly-tuned code.

However, a peculiar indirect side effect of refactoring is probably more efficient resource usage.  If the programmers understand the code better, they will likely write more effective code.   More oddly, those programmers that refactor seriously  are likely to be better software engineers than those that can't spell "refactor".

Comment: Thanks for that answer, just one tiny detail, your last comment made me go over my question several times, have I spelled refactor wrong somewhere?

Comment: No.  But if it made you nervous, you'll probably turn out to be a good software engineer :-}